# How to have multiple checkboxes use the same ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic framework for mobile app development. I set multiple checkboxes using the same ng-model, so when I click one checkbox all three checkboxes should be clicked. But the values are not stored. But I want normal HTML checkboxes (i.e) values stored in the same field in my db separated by commas.

```
<label class="item item-input item-floating-label">Gender</label>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.days" value="sunday">sunday
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.days" value="monday">monday
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve... In your example, you're using radio buttons, not checkboxes. The purpose of radio buttons is to have only one option selected. Also, can you share a bit of your controller logic? A plunker that demonstrates the problem might help too..

Comment: first thanks for reply.Sorry it's my mistake it's not radio button.Now i am change

Answer (score 1):

i am getting day's in single ng-model.

**Sample Code**

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days1" class="week_days">
        <ion-checkbox ng-model="day.select" style="border:none">{{day.name}}</ion-checkbox>
    </div>
```

**controller side**

```
$scope.days = [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Mon",
            "select": true
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Tue",
            "select": true
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Wed",
            "select": true
        }, {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Thu",
            "select": true
        }, {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Fri",
            "select": true
        }, {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Sat",
            "select": true
        }, {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Sun",
            "select": true
        }];
```

above code is default all checkbox is selected when click on checkbox then auto modified days object.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object and use it as your `ng-model`.

Check this plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/YHJDbU24BIaSrmlDTrZy?p=preview

I think this is what you want.